# Get rolling average based on time

Tags: r

I have a large dataset with two variables a time and a value. I need to create a new dataset with a rolling average for every line that calculates the mean of all values from the past 60 minutes (including the current line).

I tried a few things using tq_mutate and others but could not really get that right.

This is a sample data:

```
data= structure(list(time= structure(c(1407626653, 1407626709, 
1407629849, 1407629927, 1407630463, 1407631433), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), value= c(4, 1, 4, 3, 2, 3
)), .Names = c("time", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is the expected outcome:

```
data = structure(list(time = structure(c(1407626653, 1407626709, 1407629849, 
1407629927, 1407630463, 1407631433), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), value = c(4, 1, 4, 3, 2, 3), expected = c(4, 
2.5, 3, 3, 3, 3)), .Names = c("time", "value", "expected"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: check ```rollapply``` from zoo package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most approaches you will see involve somehow padding out the data with lots of 0s/NAs and using `rollapply`/`rollmean` (which are based on # observations windows rather than time gap, though `rollapply` lets you supply custom window sizes (in terms of observations) per observation).

The `data.table` package lets you do it efficiently by joining the table to itself on the time column such that we consider the preceding hour only.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate) # <-- only need for `- hours(1)` convenience, not strictly necessary
                   # Could instead do `- 60*60` and not load this package

setDT(data)[                                            #<Turn `data` in to a `data.table`
    J(end=unique(time), start=unique(time) - hours(1)), #<Define the start time=1 hour ago
                                                        #   and end time=current time.
    on=.(time <= end, time >= start),                   #<Join to itself restricting the
                                                        #   time to be within these windows
    list(value = mean(value)),                          #<Calc avg value
    by=.EACHI                                           #<For each join group (time window)
][,
    list(time, value)                                   #<Select the desired columns out
]                                                       # (o'wise you will get two
                                                        # identical "time" columns)

# output
                  time value
                <POSc> <num>
1: 2014-08-09 23:24:13   4.0
2: 2014-08-09 23:25:09   2.5
3: 2014-08-10 00:17:29   3.0
4: 2014-08-10 00:18:47   3.0
5: 2014-08-10 00:27:43   3.0
6: 2014-08-10 00:43:53   3.0
```

There are also other options, like simply coding up a "for each row, find all rows with time within 1 hour behind my current time, and calculate the average" - they will simply be a bit "manual" as this solution is.

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks! I really appreciate it

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept the answer.